# How to change the content of ListBox when clicked on ListBoxItem?

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I have a ListBox and I whant to bind it to a generic list with items of my type (SubscribeUnit).

```
List<SubscribeUnit> Subscribes = new List<SubscribeUnit>();
```

where

```
class SubscribeUnit
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Link { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<FeedUnit, bool> Feeds = new Dictionary<FeedUnit, bool>();
}

class FeedUnit
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Link { get; set; }
   public string PubDate { get; set; }
   public string Descr { get; set; }
}
```

When I click on ListBoxItem (that displays only the 'Title' property), the ListBox should change the content. To be exact it should now store (only the 'Title' property) FeedUnit's from `Dictionary<FeedUnit, bool> Feeds = new Dictionary<FeedUnit, bool>();`

How can I do that? Any help appriciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [data template](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) which changes itself when the [ListBoxItem.IsSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected.aspx) property becomes true using a [trigger](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html).

Comment: can you please give an example, because I'm new to wpf... not much of experience. Thx

Comment: @Pavlo Hodush Did you go through the tutorials? There is no point in writing the code for you, it will be much more helpful if you try it. First try some simple scenarios for the individual topics (like those you can find in the tutorial), only then try to combine you gained knowledge and try to figure out a solution to your original problem.

Comment: yeap, I read some tutorials... I'm sorry, it's just that I'm quicker to ask that to see you referenced some tutorials here

Comment: @Pavlo Hodush BTW, they even have the IsSelected example in the data template tutorial, which is pretty much what you are looking for.